# Using java servlet store doesn't work in my Jruby on Rails application running in Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, jrubyonrails

I'm trying to use the java servlet store instead of the :cookie_store when running in Tomcat. My application runs fine with the :cookie_store, but when using the :java_servlet_store, nothing gets stored no longer...

This seems to work, however, when I store something in the servlet_request.session, later on, I can't seem to get the value again... It seems to be gone...

In my session_store.rb:

```
require 'action_controller/session/java_servlet_store'
NameApplication::Application.config.session_store :java_servlet_store
```

In my application_controller.rb:

```
servlet_request.session.putValue(PROXYBRIDGEKEY, proxy_bridge)
```

seems to be working

But later on I'm trying to get the value and I'm getting nil...

```
servlet_request.session.getValue(PROXYBRIDGEKEY)
```

Any ideas as what could be the problem here?

To be clear, putting the value in the session does work (tested that). With a new html request, getting the value doesn't work anymore. So, there must be a problem with getting the cookie I guess...

Comment: and how's the cookie doing - you mention it might be a cookie issue, would be great to know how it acts. check JSSESSIONID set on first request and than compare if the second request is sending the same cookie, if not than it's not set correctly (e.g. wrong domain ? are you behind a proxy ?) you can also try to rule out whether it's a Tomcat configuration issue by trying to run the app with another server e.g. Trinidad ... if the issue does not persist than it's something the way your Tomcat is configured.

Comment: Perhaps this may be solution for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940143/how-can-i-create-a-servlet-with-jruby-running-with-jetty

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you could try is defining your store as:

require 'action_controller/session/java_servlet_store'

NameApplication::Application.config.session_store :java_servlet_store, :key => "MyKey"

I'm not sure it's relevant, but it was necessary for the :cookie_store.  It could make sense that you need to identify your servlet key in the java_servlet_store as well.  This key will be the key of the cookie sent to the browser for subsequent requests.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If that didn't work for you, also make sure that you set the java_servlet_store key to "JSESSIONID" to use the standard JVM session.

From there in Ruby, all you need to do to read and write session (this will be accessing the JVM session object):

session.id
session[:yoursessionvariable]

Note: If you have not initialized session (assign a session variable value), session will be nil (making session.id undefined) until you do so.